# Duplicate question notice checks closed duplicate for answers instead of target

Tags: bug, status-completed, closing, exact-duplicates

In March 2016, [Exact duplicate doesn't require answer but claims one exists](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22898/exact-duplicate-doesnt-require-answer-but-claims-one-exists) was implemented, which purported to show a different notice if the duplicate target has had no answers.

However, for many years, probably since its original implementation, it has been wrongly checking the closed duplicate question rather than the target question.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290420/what-is-the-difference-between-exact-duplicate-and-just-duplicate